# How do I set up DataTables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

Ok so I have a table of t-shirt designs, and I'm trying to use DataTables. I used the download builder and chose the buttons extension. The table seems to be using DataTables, but I dont see the paginate. Am I missing something? Sorry I'm very new to DataTables.

```js
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/t/dt/jqc-1.12.0,dt-1.10.11,b-1.1.2,b-colvis-1.1.2,r-2.0.2/datatables.min.css"/>
 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/t/dt/jqc-1.12.0,dt-1.10.11,b-1.1.2,b-colvis-1.1.2,r-2.0.2/datatables.min.js"></script>

<script>$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable();
       });

</script>
```

```css
#mainProduct {
    
    background-color: #E8E8E8;
    border: solid white;
}
.container {
  max-width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  margin-left: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
.container div {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  display: none;
}
.container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.card-container {
  height: 200px;
  perspective: 600;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}
.card {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  width: 100%;
}
.card:hover {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.card .side {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
.card .back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
#example {margin-left: 15px;}
#description {text-align:center; margin-top: 25%; font-size: 12px;}
```

```html
<!-- Product listings -->
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" text-align="center">

<!--T-REX COFFEE-->
<tr>
 <td id="mainProduct"><a href="http://www.cafepress.com/mizoo/13366446">
   <div class="card-container">
    <div class="card">
     <div class="side"><img src="http://t12.deviantart.net/BrcRPOF9yezzdQA7qI0GGt9CQpA=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre02/0cc5/th/pre/i/2016/059/a/a/1_t_rex_coffee_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfftx.png">
     </div>
    <div class="side back">
     <p id="description">What better way to show you love coffee than with a prehistoric predator!</p>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</a>
</td>

<!--TAFFY CAT BATUSI-->
<td id="mainProduct"><a href="http://www.cafepress.com/mizoo/13366550">
<div class="card-container">
 <div class="card">
  <div class="side"><img src="http://t02.deviantart.net/_WQLrq--RN0K8ixtplOOzyahVko=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre14/aefe/th/pre/i/2016/059/b/7/14_taffycat_batusi_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfg15.png">
  </div>
  <div class="side back"><p id="description">What's better than Taffy Cat doing the Batusi? Taffy cat doing the Batusi on a t-shirt!</p>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
</a>
</td>

<!--SMILEY CONVERSE-->

<td id="mainProduct"><a href="">
<div class="card-container">
 <div class="card">
  <div class="side"><img src="http://t12.deviantart.net/kxTUWMz6TsfYVFSd_YSycsGW70I=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre09/bbd1/th/pre/i/2016/059/8/f/36_smiley_red_shoe_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfg7p.png">
  </div>
  <div class="side back"><p id="description">Smiley red shoe. Because ... shoe!</p>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
</a>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>

<!--I'M BUFF-->

<td id="mainProduct"><a href="">
<div class="card-container">
 <div class="card">
  <div class="side"><img src="http://t07.deviantart.net/UCKBK6KyJzceGbuB8szw-ucEZ2Y=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre09/a544/th/pre/i/2016/059/e/9/18_buff_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfq5g.png">
  </div>
  <div class="side back"><p id="description">Because thinking you are something is half the journey of being something ...</p>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
</a>
</td>
<!--Curvy-->
<td id="mainProduct"><a href="">
<div class="card-container">
 <div class="card">
  <div class="side"><img src="http://t08.deviantart.net/Lljv-RDFIKZCRuTf-GAxc0_BI0o=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre06/da78/th/pre/i/2016/059/7/c/19_curvy_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfqau.png">
  </div>
  <div class="side back"><p id="description">Because thinking you are something is half the journey of being something ...</p>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
</a>
</td>
<!--Love female&female-->
<td id="mainProduct"><a href="">
<div class="card-container">
 <div class="card">
  <div class="side"><img src="http://t01.deviantart.net/hGoyHjNSwG-HMyz4tBPYyWBJnD8=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre01/bc6e/th/pre/i/2016/059/c/8/42_love3_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfo91.png">
  </div>
  <div class="side back"><p id="description">Celebrate love and diversity!</p>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
</a>
</td>

</tr>

<tr>
<!--love male&male-->
<td id="mainProduct"><a href="">
<div class="card-container">
 <div class="card">
  <div class="side"><img src="http://t04.deviantart.net/cgbfKcYI8e56QSdswTVHPMG8LOI=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre12/3e14/th/pre/i/2016/059/2/b/41_love2_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfo4w.png">
  </div>
  <div class="side back"><p id="description">Celebrate love and diversity!</p>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
</a>
</td>
<!--420 Deadpool-->
<td id="mainProduct"><a href="">
<div class="card-container">
 <div class="card">
  <div class="side"><img src="http://t08.deviantart.net/yUSAlWXmNVP8S_eBilkJrQVe3h0=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre01/9557/th/pre/i/2016/059/2/d/26_420pool_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfltp.png">
  </div>
  <div class="side back"><p id="description"></p>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
</a>
</td>
<!--Super Taffy Cat-->
<td id="mainProduct"><a href="">
<div class="card-container">
 <div class="card">
  <div class="side"><img src="http://t07.deviantart.net/_ynkAcDVU3UrjIgmeUhz49Itxzs=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre10/c388/th/pre/i/2016/059/5/c/15_taffycat14_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfmhe.png">
  </div>
  <div class="side back"><p id="description"></p>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
</a>
</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<!--Taffy Cat book-->
<td id="mainProduct"><a href="">
<div class="card-container">
 <div class="card">
  <div class="side"><img src="http://t02.deviantart.net/D6FyR9Ku_FWdtRRSJQSH90Fy9z4=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre11/5f3a/th/pre/i/2016/059/6/4/13_taffycat12_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfng8.png">
  </div>
  <div class="side back"><p id="description"></p>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
</a>
</td>
<!--Prop of 420-->
<td id="mainProduct"><a href="">
<div class="card-container">
 <div class="card">
  <div class="side"><img src="http://t15.deviantart.net/Br5zZ0fwMNx3Tyebl0HT7TjB9GI=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre06/32ac/th/pre/i/2016/059/9/4/24_propertyof420_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfope.png">
  </div>
  <div class="side back"><p id="description"></p>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
</a>
</td>
<!--All that list-->
<td id="mainProduct"><a href="">
<div class="card-container">
 <div class="card">
  <div class="side"><img src="http://t09.deviantart.net/ugkgkxMIkDWBjB-SEKEJDpHE4Zs=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre02/00e6/th/pre/i/2016/059/b/c/43__checklist_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfkdq.png">
  </div>
  <div class="side back"><p id="description"></p>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
</a>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<!--Taffy Cat book-->
<td id="mainProduct"><a href="">
<div class="card-container">
 <div class="card">
  <div class="side"><img src="http://t02.deviantart.net/D6FyR9Ku_FWdtRRSJQSH90Fy9z4=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre11/5f3a/th/pre/i/2016/059/6/4/13_taffycat12_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfng8.png">
  </div>
  <div class="side back"><p id="description"></p>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
</a>
</td>
<!--Prop of 420-->
<td id="mainProduct"><a href="">
<div class="card-container">
 <div class="card">
  <div class="side"><img src="http://t15.deviantart.net/Br5zZ0fwMNx3Tyebl0HT7TjB9GI=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre06/32ac/th/pre/i/2016/059/9/4/24_propertyof420_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfope.png">
  </div>
  <div class="side back"><p id="description"></p>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
</a>
</td>
<!--All that list-->
<td id="mainProduct"><a href="">
<div class="card-container">
 <div class="card">
  <div class="side"><img src="http://t09.deviantart.net/ugkgkxMIkDWBjB-SEKEJDpHE4Zs=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre02/00e6/th/pre/i/2016/059/b/c/43__checklist_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfkdq.png">
  </div>
  <div class="side back"><p id="description"></p>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
</a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moved my answer to jsfiddle b/c i hate stack overflows code editor.
https://jsfiddle.net/guanzo/3tjf87kt/1/

From the official docs http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/

> In order for DataTables to be able to function correctly, the HTML for the target table must be laid out in a well formed manner with the 'thead' and 'tbody' sections declared. For example:

All i did was add a `thead`

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>one</th>
        <th>two</th>
        <th>three</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

And wrap your existing rows with a `tbody`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajReddy/fckhhkej/1/)

You had to format the table to have proper `thead` tags and `tbody`, only then the plugin will apply the datatables without errors. For more info [read more here](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/)

```js
$('#example').dataTable();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/t/dt/jqc-1.12.0,dt-1.10.11,b-1.1.2,b-colvis-1.1.2,r-2.0.2/datatables.min.css"/>
 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/t/dt/jqc-1.12.0,dt-1.10.11,b-1.1.2,b-colvis-1.1.2,r-2.0.2/datatables.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" text-align="center">
<thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
<tbody>
<!--T-REX COFFEE-->
<tr>
 <td id="mainProduct"><a href="http://www.cafepress.com/mizoo/13366446">
   <div class="card-container">
    <div class="card">
     <div class="side"><img src="http://t12.deviantart.net/BrcRPOF9yezzdQA7qI0GGt9CQpA=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre02/0cc5/th/pre/i/2016/059/a/a/1_t_rex_coffee_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfftx.png">
     </div>
    <div class="side back">
     <p id="description">What better way to show you love coffee than with a prehistoric predator!</p>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</a>
</td>

<!--TAFFY CAT BATUSI-->
<td id="mainProduct"><a href="http://www.cafepress.com/mizoo/13366550">
<div class="card-container">
 <div class="card">
  <div class="side"><img src="http://t02.deviantart.net/_WQLrq--RN0K8ixtplOOzyahVko=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre14/aefe/th/pre/i/2016/059/b/7/14_taffycat_batusi_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfg15.png">
  </div>
  <div class="side back"><p id="description">What's better than Taffy Cat doing the Batusi? Taffy cat doing the Batusi on a t-shirt!</p>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
</a>
</td>

<!--SMILEY CONVERSE-->

<td id="mainProduct"><a href="">
<div class="card-container">
 <div class="card">
  <div class="side"><img src="http://t12.deviantart.net/kxTUWMz6TsfYVFSd_YSycsGW70I=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre09/bbd1/th/pre/i/2016/059/8/f/36_smiley_red_shoe_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfg7p.png">
  </div>
  <div class="side back"><p id="description">Smiley red shoe. Because ... shoe!</p>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
</a>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>

<!--I'M BUFF-->

<td id="mainProduct"><a href="">
<div class="card-container">
 <div class="card">
  <div class="side"><img src="http://t07.deviantart.net/UCKBK6KyJzceGbuB8szw-ucEZ2Y=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre09/a544/th/pre/i/2016/059/e/9/18_buff_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfq5g.png">
  </div>
  <div class="side back"><p id="description">Because thinking you are something is half the journey of being something ...</p>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
</a>
</td>
<!--Curvy-->
<td id="mainProduct"><a href="">
<div class="card-container">
 <div class="card">
  <div class="side"><img src="http://t08.deviantart.net/Lljv-RDFIKZCRuTf-GAxc0_BI0o=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre06/da78/th/pre/i/2016/059/7/c/19_curvy_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfqau.png">
  </div>
  <div class="side back"><p id="description">Because thinking you are something is half the journey of being something ...</p>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
</a>
</td>
<!--Love female&female-->
<td id="mainProduct"><a href="">
<div class="card-container">
 <div class="card">
  <div class="side"><img src="http://t01.deviantart.net/hGoyHjNSwG-HMyz4tBPYyWBJnD8=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre01/bc6e/th/pre/i/2016/059/c/8/42_love3_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfo91.png">
  </div>
  <div class="side back"><p id="description">Celebrate love and diversity!</p>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
</a>
</td>

</tr>

<tr>
<!--love male&male-->
<td id="mainProduct"><a href="">
<div class="card-container">
 <div class="card">
  <div class="side"><img src="http://t04.deviantart.net/cgbfKcYI8e56QSdswTVHPMG8LOI=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre12/3e14/th/pre/i/2016/059/2/b/41_love2_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfo4w.png">
  </div>
  <div class="side back"><p id="description">Celebrate love and diversity!</p>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
</a>
</td>
<!--420 Deadpool-->
<td id="mainProduct"><a href="">
<div class="card-container">
 <div class="card">
  <div class="side"><img src="http://t08.deviantart.net/yUSAlWXmNVP8S_eBilkJrQVe3h0=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre01/9557/th/pre/i/2016/059/2/d/26_420pool_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfltp.png">
  </div>
  <div class="side back"><p id="description"></p>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
</a>
</td>
<!--Super Taffy Cat-->
<td id="mainProduct"><a href="">
<div class="card-container">
 <div class="card">
  <div class="side"><img src="http://t07.deviantart.net/_ynkAcDVU3UrjIgmeUhz49Itxzs=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre10/c388/th/pre/i/2016/059/5/c/15_taffycat14_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfmhe.png">
  </div>
  <div class="side back"><p id="description"></p>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
</a>
</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<!--Taffy Cat book-->
<td id="mainProduct"><a href="">
<div class="card-container">
 <div class="card">
  <div class="side"><img src="http://t02.deviantart.net/D6FyR9Ku_FWdtRRSJQSH90Fy9z4=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre11/5f3a/th/pre/i/2016/059/6/4/13_taffycat12_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfng8.png">
  </div>
  <div class="side back"><p id="description"></p>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
</a>
</td>
<!--Prop of 420-->
<td id="mainProduct"><a href="">
<div class="card-container">
 <div class="card">
  <div class="side"><img src="http://t15.deviantart.net/Br5zZ0fwMNx3Tyebl0HT7TjB9GI=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre06/32ac/th/pre/i/2016/059/9/4/24_propertyof420_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfope.png">
  </div>
  <div class="side back"><p id="description"></p>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
</a>
</td>
<!--All that list-->
<td id="mainProduct"><a href="">
<div class="card-container">
 <div class="card">
  <div class="side"><img src="http://t09.deviantart.net/ugkgkxMIkDWBjB-SEKEJDpHE4Zs=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre02/00e6/th/pre/i/2016/059/b/c/43__checklist_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfkdq.png">
  </div>
  <div class="side back"><p id="description"></p>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
</a>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<!--Taffy Cat book-->
<td id="mainProduct"><a href="">
<div class="card-container">
 <div class="card">
  <div class="side"><img src="http://t02.deviantart.net/D6FyR9Ku_FWdtRRSJQSH90Fy9z4=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre11/5f3a/th/pre/i/2016/059/6/4/13_taffycat12_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfng8.png">
  </div>
  <div class="side back"><p id="description"></p>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
</a>
</td>
<!--Prop of 420-->
<td id="mainProduct"><a href="">
<div class="card-container">
 <div class="card">
  <div class="side"><img src="http://t15.deviantart.net/Br5zZ0fwMNx3Tyebl0HT7TjB9GI=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre06/32ac/th/pre/i/2016/059/9/4/24_propertyof420_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfope.png">
  </div>
  <div class="side back"><p id="description"></p>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
</a>
</td>
<!--All that list-->
<td id="mainProduct"><a href="">
<div class="card-container">
 <div class="card">
  <div class="side"><img src="http://t09.deviantart.net/ugkgkxMIkDWBjB-SEKEJDpHE4Zs=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre02/00e6/th/pre/i/2016/059/b/c/43__checklist_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfkdq.png">
  </div>
  <div class="side back"><p id="description"></p>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
</a>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

So as mentioned the only problem was you missed out the `thead` tag and also to wrap your `tr` tags inside a `tbody`